# Clarity of understanding of the meaning

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

For example, I want someone doesn't do something then which one will be correct? And also I want him to do this.

Does the first one mean that he will not do this and the second one Doesn't it mean he will do this? What do the others mean?

> I ask you not to do this, do not ask him.
>
> I ask you not to do this, ask him.
>
> I ask you to do this, do not ask him.
>
> I ask you not to do this, ask him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those expressions is idiomatic English.

*I want someone doesn't do something* would have to be "I don't want someone to do something"

If you were requesting another person to pass on the message, you could say "I ask you to ask him not to do it."

Comment: Is it correct to say like this or is it wrong too?: "I want someone to not do something" or "I want someone to not did something".

Comment: I wondered about "I want him not to do it". It is possible, but would not be the usual way of expressing the idea.  You can't say _to not did_ - the infinitive of the verb is _to do_.

Comment: I also wanted to ask about it: if add "so" before "someone", will it be sound fine?

Comment: Do you mean "I want so someone..."? No, this is not idiomatic English.